What is the Hausdorff dimension of the set on which this exponential sum is bounded?
This is a direct follow up to For which rationals is this exponential sum bounded?
Given $x \in [0, 1]$, we denote by $e(x)$ the complex number $e^{2 \pi i x}$.
What is the Hausdorff dimension of the set of $x$ for which the sum
$$A_N(x)\, :=\, \sum_{n = 0}^N e(2^n x)$$
remains bounded as $N \to \infty$?
Remarks:

We allow the bound to depend on $x$, but not $N$.

It can be shown that the sum is unbounded for Lebesgue almost every $x$.

The following contraption can be used to construct some irrationals for which the sum is bounded.



Side remark: $\int_0^1 |\sum_{n=0}^N e(2^n x)|^2 dx = N+1$.

@mathworker21 Right, one could say this follows from the doubling map being measure preserving wrt the standard measure on the circle...

Although I'm not sure if that's the reasoning you used.

More classically, $\int_0^1 e(\alpha x) dx=1$ if $\alpha=0$ and $0$ otherwise. @NateRiver
